# I/O Exception and Unable to find element In IE using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, selenium

The below code works fine with Firefox and chrome but shows errors when executed in IE.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "G:\\Selenium\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=ZDziUrLDEuLpiAeD44H4BA");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium");
```

The error displayed is `I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Jan 24, 2014 3:44:04 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:`

Comment: What version of IE? IE 11 is entirely unsupported yet.

Comment: The version of IE is 10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was with my IE settings. The problem was resolved when the security settings in IE was changed to "Enable Protected Mode" for "Internet", "Local Intranet", "Trusted Sites" and "Restricted Sites". You can change it by going to Internet Options security tab and enable check box "Enable Protected Mode" for all the zones. I was able to get these information from the link http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html

Answer (score 0):

**Please review the following Python code (should by similar for Java):**

```
from selenium import webdriver

def findElement(browser):
    browser.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=ZDziUrLDEuLpiAeD44H4BA")
    element = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
    return element.get_attribute("outerHTML")

ieBrowser = webdriver.Ie()
print "IE: "+findElement(ieBrowser)

ffBrowser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile())
print "FF: "+findElement(ffBrowser)
```

**The output of the code above is:**

```
IE: <input id="lst-ib" class="lst lst-tbb" title="חיפוש" name="q" maxLength="2048" value="" size="41" type="text" autocomplete="off">

FF: <input spellcheck="false" dir="ltr" style="border: medium none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; background: url(&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 6; left: 0px; outline: medium none;" id="gbqfq" class="gbqfif" name="q" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text">
```

**So I am able to find the element you're looking for in both browsers (using Selenium v2.39.00).**

Comment: Both options are not working.. same error displayed.. error displayed even before google loads fully.

Comment: OK; answer revised. You might wanna check you're Selenium version, as well as the version of your IEDriverServer.exe file.

Comment: You can check the source code of this web-page, manually on each browser. In FF you should be able to find `name=q`, and in IE you should be able to find `name="q"`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try waiting for the element to be visible with [Explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp),

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("gbqfq"))).sendKeys("Selenium");
```

Comment: The error occurred now also: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.id: gbqfq)
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Configuring enable protected mode (Internet, Local Intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites), in the four options was enough for me.