# NoSuchWindowException was unhandled : Unable to find element on closed window. IE 11 - Selenium C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, selenium, internet-explorer-11

May be this question has been asked many times before. But i went through all the related questions in stackoverflow , but couldn't find any satisfactory solution.

Well i'am writing a selenium automation code in VS2010 using C#, IE11 is my web browser on which i'am performing testing. Using IEDriverServer 32bit version in Windows 7 to open IE instance.

I already knew that there is some compatibility kind of issue between selenium and IE 11, but still my code worked fine up till now when i started getting this Error - " NoSuchWindowException was unhandled : Unable to find element on closed window."

Below are my steps:-

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("D:\\");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://aiaw00572.belldev.dev.bce.ca:8060/UTM_MechHDTool_UserWebApp");

driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_cpMainContent_radcboTaskType_Input"), 10).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='ctl00_cpMainContent_radcboTaskType_DropDown']/div/ul/li[2]")).Click(); (this step select a drop down option which performs a postback on the page)

driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_cpMainContent_utmTaskGrid_ctl00_ctl06_imgbtnStartWorking")).Click();//Getting error on this step. Earlier i was not getting it anywhere
```

I searched for the solutions for this problem and came to know about one solution in which some registry change has to be done to solve it, though that also does not confirm that it will solve the problem. But the problem here i can't even check this solution as i don't have any administrator privilege in my system.

So just wanted to know if someone else has also faced the problem and came with some solution, so he/she can share it here please as i badly need a solution in here for this situation.

Comment: From the message in the exception.. is the browser window open when you do the last FindElement().Click() ?

Comment: yeah it is open. But i think somehow the connection is getting broken(just a guess).

Comment: Try for an older version of the browser then ?

Comment: Yeah i thought of this thing. Well already raised a request in my office to uninstall IE11 and install IE 8. Let see if it will work or not.

Comment: Yeah checked in IE 8, it's working. Though i think i would have to find the solution of this IE 11 as in future our web application will be moved to IE 11. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using latest build of IE11 i.e. with latest updates, sometimes particular build of IE causes issues.

Comment: Yeah i had the latest version of IE11. But that was not working.

Comment: Yes, there are registry changes needed to allow IE11 and WebDriver to work correctly with one another. This is absolutely paramount to be tried first before going down the rabbit hole even further, so please, just ask your administrator to get this sorted. If it doesn't work, let's go back to the drawing board, but there is no point continuing until you've done the *very basic* steps that are required for it to even work in the first place.

Comment: might be silly but try changing the url with ip

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me after running IEDriverServer as admin or setting protected mode for all zones (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21373224/217408)

Answer (score 5):

Error:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

**Step1.** Change Windows registry.
If you use Internet Explorer 11 x64 (64 bit),
create file **ie11_win64.reg** has content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE]
"iexplore.exe"=dword:00000000
```

Then run it.

If you use Internet Explorer 11 x86 (32 bit),
create file **ie11_win32.reg** has content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE]
"iexplore.exe"=dword:00000000
```

Then run it.

**Step2.** Setting in internet explorer. Uncheck all (or Check all, must be the same for zones: Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is the complete answer on this page

Answer (score 0):

For me the aswear was to download this registry file from http://heliumhq.com/docs/internet_explorer and to run it

Answer (score 0):

In our case tests were based on Jbehave and Serenity. The First test always pass and second fails with mentioned exception. Opening new Webdriver instance for each scenario helps to resolve issue.