# VSTS 2010 Premium Coded-ui fails sometimes to locate the captured controls in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, coded-ui-tests

Currently we are using VSTS 2010 premium for our coded ui test automation. Also we used IE-8 initially for our execution. Now we are planning to migrate to windows 8 OS and hence we upgraded IE-8 to IE-11. After upgrading to IE-11, we are facing some problems like,
**1.** While trying to locate the captured control, coded-ui throws error as "**The control cannot be located. Unable to find Windows Internet Explorer window with 'Application name - Internet Explorer - Windows Internet Explorer' in the title.**" But if we close visual studio and then try after sometime, its working but its taking longer time to locate a single control.
**2.** Also, during execution, entering values in edit box is working fine but, finally application hangs while coded-ui tries to perform button click action like clicking submit button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that a security update is preventing you from doing this testing. I was using IE 11 till November last year when a security update hid the controls. It's possible this is as far back as 2013 VS2010 for KB2870699 https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800953/security-update-kb2870699-for-ie-breaks-existing-coded-ui-tests

Answer (score 0):

When I looked into this I could not find a way of un-hiding these elements such as hovering over the parent. Research suggested a Security update in IE caused the tests to stop working. Options for a work around in the order best to worst:

1. Use the [Selenium](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d) add on with support for the newer browsers. Other benefits including cross browser testing with Chrome and Firefox.
2. Update the Visual Studios test project to a newer version. You could try this out with a [Visual Studios Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx)
3. Go back to IE 8 - not ideal as the % of users
   still with IE 8 is minimal. I  would recommend a VM (Virtual Machine ) if you go down
   the 2nd or 3rd path.
4. Remove security updates for IE 11 - As you probably are
   aware this presents a significant security issue and you need to mitigate associated risks. Disable auto update through Internet options -> About Internet Explorer -> uncheck install new versions automatically

Comment: Will this selenium add on work with vs 2010? Because, its mentioned like it will work with VS 2012 Update 4, VS 2013 and VS 2013 Update 4

Comment: It will work with changes to the registry as pointed out by [Arran](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1173729/arran) ["there are registry changes needed to allow IE11 and WebDriver to work"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712417/nosuchwindowexception-was-unhandled-unable-to-find-element-on-closed-window-i)